# SSH with ipv6 working only if I pass %en0 with my ipv6 address

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, ssh, ipv6

I am trying to ssh with Mac OS X (10.10.1 Yosemite) terminal using ipv6.
If I use command like

```
ssh username@ipv6_address
```

It's not working and I am getting error "No Route to Host".
But If I use command like (with %en0)

```
ssh username@ipv6_address%en0
```

It's working and I am able to SSH with ipv6 address..

Can you please guide me what's the reason of not working without %en0?

Thanks.

Comment: Which IPv6 addresses are you using. Having to specify the interface is only necessary when using link-local addresses (those starting with `fe80:`). Those are not routable and not very convenient to use. You'll want to get routable IPv6 addresses (from an ISP, a tunnel provider or ULA) when using IPv6.

Comment: @SanderSteffann Yes, It's starting with fe80. Means to connect with local need to specify interface?

Comment: Yes. I'll put this into an answer

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/99746/144961

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to connect to an unroutable address like link-local you need to specify the interface. This is because for unroutable addresses your system can't determine the outgoing interface by looking at the routing table.

Unroutable destinations include link-local addresses (fe80::) and link-local multicast (ff02::) and more.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For routable ipv6 address, I can get from ISP, correct? or need any changes in network configuration?

Comment: From your ISP, or for internal use (not to connect to the internet) you can generate your own ULA addresses.

Comment: Thank you for this @SanderSteffann! Do you happen to have any idea how to specify a link-local IPv6 destination in Safari or Chrome on MacOS? With routable inet6 addresses, putting the address in square brackets works: `http://[fed0:ad::2]/login`. I can't figure out how to give either browser the interface information though. Putting it in the brackets not surprisingly makes it do a search for what I've entered, since it's no longer a valid inet6 address.