# ping and ssh to IPv6-only server returns Unknown host

Tags: terminal, mojave

I got a server with IPv6 **only**.

```
ping 2001:19f0:5:65e0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
ping: cannot resolve 2001:19f0:5:65e0:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx: Unknown host
ssh root@xxxx:xxxx:x:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
ssh: connect to host xxxx:xxxx:x:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx port 22: No route to host
```

The Ubuntu 21.04 server is up and running. I am able to login to the browser version of the console. It's the OS terminal that's not recognizing the IPv6 address.

I am on macOS Mojave

UPDATED:

```
ping6 ipv6.google.com
ping6: UDP connect: No route to host
```

So this is my ISP blocking ?

Comment: What is the first xxxx of the address if fe80:: see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157330/ssh-with-ipv6-working-only-if-i-pass-en0-with-my-ipv6-address?rq=1

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-test-ipv6-network-with-ping6-command/ - `ping 2606:4700:10::6816:bd6
ping: cannot resolve 2606:4700:10::6816:bd6: Unknown host`

Comment: `ping6 ipv6.google.com
ping6: UDP connect: No route to host`
So this is my ISP blocking ?

Comment: Enter those comments in the question it is different to the one I linked to, also what exactly do you type in safari. .

Comment: Do you have **IPv6** configured on your network adapter?

Comment: It's automatic - https://imgur.com/a/UTqyTZp

Comment: While you are showing it set to **Automatically** in the screenshot, nonetheless, it does not appear to be configured, as it certainly isn't showing similar to mine.  https://i.imgur.com/274CcYO.jpeg

Comment: From **Terminal**, do you see any `inet6` output from this _command_: `ifconfig | grep 'inet6'`

Comment: Yes. `inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
 inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
 inet6 fe80::aede:48ff:fe00:1122%en5 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x8 
 inet6 fe80::103b:4878:1020:2392%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0xa 
 inet6 fe80::78bf:64ff:fe38:28bd%awdl0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xc 
 inet6 fe80::dc61:1f88:e7b4:983e%utun0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x12 
 inet6 fe80::7127:c921:639b:d4f2%utun1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x13 
 inet6 fe80::2042:db8d:3e9a:84f5%utun2 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x14 `

Comment: I switched on my VPN and all works fine. So it was the ISP blocking it !